# PHP Put Span Class into Brackets regex

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-replace, str-replace

This is what I have so far:

```
$phones = "Samsung Galaxy S8~LG G6~iPhone 7 Plus~ Motorola Z2";

$phones  = str_replace("Galaxy S", '<span class="galaxy">galaxy</span>', $phones);

$value = preg_replace('/(\d+.*?)(~)/', '($1)$2', $phones . "~");

$value = "<li>". str_replace("~", ",</li><li>", substr($value,0,-1)) . "</li>";

Echo $value;
```

and the result is:

- Samsung **galaxy** (8),
- LG G(6),
- iPhone (7 Plus),
- Motorola Z(2)

What I'm trying to do is to put the span class inside the brackets so it will be:

- Samsung ( **galaxy** 8 ),
- LG G(6),
- iPhone (7 Plus),
- Motorola Z(2)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pattern Demo/Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/HZrOmc/4)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/691586c404891f2859e54a6b71ee92f7525fe417))

```
$phone='Samsung Galaxy S8~LG G6~iPhone 7 Plus~ Motorola Z2';
$match='/Galaxy S(\d+)/';
$replace='( <span class="galaxy">galaxy</span> $1 )';
echo preg_replace($match,$replace,$phone);
```

Unrendered Output:

```
Samsung ( <span class="galaxy">galaxy</span> 8 )~LG G6~iPhone 7 Plus~ Motorola Z2
```

---

Here is the full `<ul>` block:

```
$phone='Samsung Galaxy S8~LG G6~iPhone 7 Plus~ Motorola Z2';
$match='/Galaxy S(\d+)/';
$replace='( <span class="galaxy">galaxy</span> $1 )';
echo '<ul><li>',str_replace('~',',</li><li>',preg_replace($match,$replace,$phone)),'</li></ul>';
```

Unrendered Output:

```
<ul><li>Samsung ( <span class="galaxy">galaxy</span> 8 ),</li><li>LG G6,</li><li>iPhone 7 Plus,</li><li> Motorola Z2</li></ul>
```

---

---

Final Alteration:

```
$phones="Samsung Galaxy S8~LG G6~iPhone 7 Plus~ Motorola Z2";
$patterns=[
    '/(?:Galaxy S)?\d[^~]*/', // match (optional Galaxy S), number, optional trailing text
    '/~ ?/',  // match delimiter and optional trailing space (at Motorola)
    '/Galaxy S/'  // literally match Galaxy S
];
$replacements=[
    '($0)',  // wrap full string match in parentheses
    '</li><li>',  // use closing and opening li tags as new delimiter
    '<span class="galaxy">Galaxy</span> '  // tagged text (note: G & space after </span>)
];
$full_list='<ul><li>'.preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$phones).'</li></ul>';
echo $full_list;
```

Unrendered Output:

```
<ul><li>Samsung (<span class="galaxy">galaxy</span> 8)</li><li>LG G(6)</li><li>iPhone (7 Plus)</li><li>Motorola Z(2)</li></ul>
```